# TeamsBot doesn't have conversation references

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have Teams Bot with a code pretty much like example of [proactive messages from ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet).
When I run bot locally - either with Bot Emulator, or Ngrok + Teams Bot registered in Azure, notifications work as expected. When I publish my bot to Azure (as an app service), it does not have conversation references to send proactive message.
My notify controller looks the same as the sample, I just added printing how many conv references are there.

```
public class NotifyController : ControllerBase {
    private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter _adapter;
    private readonly string _appId;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> _conversationReferences;

    public NotifyController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IConfiguration configuration, ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences) {
        _adapter = adapter;
        _conversationReferences = conversationReferences;
        _appId = configuration["MicrosoftAppId"] ?? "<my-app-id>";
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Get() {
        foreach (var conversationReference in _conversationReferences.Values) {
            Debug.WriteLine($"awaiting callback from convdId({conversationReference.Conversation.Id}) from user {conversationReference.User.Name}{conversationReference.User.Id}");
            await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback, default);
        }

        return new ContentResult() {
            Content = $"<html><body><h1>Proactive messages have been sent to {_conversationReferences.Count} conversations.</h1></body></html>",
            ContentType = "text/html",
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        };
    }

    private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("proactive hello", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

ConfigureServices in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddHttpClient().AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();
        services.AddSingleton<IStorage, MemoryStorage>();
        services.AddSingleton<UserState>();
        services.AddSingleton<ConversationState>();
        services.AddSingleton<MainDialog>();
        services.AddTransient<IBot, DialogBot<MainDialog>>();
        services.AddSingleton<ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference>>();
    }
```

Also in Bot code there are functions (does not matter of the commented function is uncommented, behavior is the same):

```
public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
    await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
    //AddConversationReference(turnContext.Activity as Activity);
    await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
}
    ...
private void AddConversationReference(Activity activity) {
    var conversationReference = activity.GetConversationReference();
    ConversationReferences.AddOrUpdate(conversationReference.User.Id, conversationReference, (key, newValue) => conversationReference);
}

protected override Task OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    AddConversationReference(turnContext.Activity as Activity);
    return base.OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
}
```

I don't know where the references are set to investigate why they are not set :/ running locally, I can see proper number of conversations.
I also added logs to see if [comments of Hilton Giesenow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71831343/teamsbot-doesnt-have-conversation-references/71831541?noredirect=1#comment126947750_71831541) are applicable; looks like conversation references are not set, so I don't have any data to save. Sometimes (I don't know under what circumstances) `OnTurnAsync` is called and then there is data in conversation reference.

Answer (score 1):

What you're using is just a *sample*, as a result it's there to teach important concepts, but not meant to be used 100% as is in production. In the sample, for instance, it stores all the data for the application in memory (notice this line: `services.AddSingleton<IStorage, MemoryStorage>();`). That means that the information being stored, like the conversation references, are only available while the application is running, and only on the single computer it's running on.

For a production scenario, you need to be saving these conversation references to a "durable" storage (one that lasts as long as you need), for example a database or a file storage of some sort. Then you can retrieve it from that storage whenever you need it, e.g. to send a proactive message.

On a related note, when you store something in a permanent location, you generally need to "key" it, which means to store it in a way you can uniquely find each record as needed in the future. In the case of a Teams bot, using the AadObjectId for the user is a good starting point for this, as it's unique to every single user.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I understand that it should be still working. The conv reference is empty even though I right now talking with the bot.

Comment: You haven't shown in your code samples above how or where you -capture- the conversation references in the first place - please update that.

Comment: What do you mean by capture? The only place I got them assigned is `NotifyController` constructor

Comment: It looks like the `AddConversationReference` method is what is doing the work, but it's currently not being called (`//AddConversationReference(turnContext.Activity as Activity);` is commented out)

Comment: In any case, as I said, that will only store in memory right now, so if for example your bot state is reset, it will get lost. This would happen, for instance, every time you redeploy your bot - you should look to save it to something durable, like a database, or blob storage, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. But so far I am sure that bot is not reset, because I have a conversation with it at the same time.